# Fourier transform of a sequence and inverse fourier transform

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, fourier-transform

If

$$
h(k) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2l+1} & -l \leq k \leq l \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Where $l \geq 0$ is some integer. 
I've done some computation and the summation

$$
F[h](\omega)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} h(k)e^{j\omega k} = \frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)} = H(\omega)
$$

If I consider $h$ convolved with itself $n$ times I have
$$
F[h*h\ldots*h](\omega) = H^{n}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\left(2l+1\right)^n}\left(\frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)}\right)^n
$$

Now I'd like to compute (in closed form) the integral

$$
I_n(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} H^n(\omega)e^{j\omega k} d\omega
$$

The clue I had was using the residual theorem somehow, If I wanted to compute it exactly. However I have some difficulties with the calculation because of the dependencies with $n$. I would be happy with an asymptotic estimation as well since in practice I'm interested in large $n$. So the difficulty is given by finding an asymptotic approximation of

$$
\frac{1}{\left(2l+1\right)^n}\left(\frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)}\right)^n \approx \;?
$$

(I guess when $n$ tends to infinity $I_n$ should look like a Gaussian).

**Update**: From [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) in wikipedia I know that:

$$
1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^l \cos(k\omega) =  \frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)}
$$

Which implies
$$
\left( \frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)} \right)^n = \left( 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^l \cos(k\omega) \right)^n
$$

and I'm stuck again...

**Update 2**:

Not sure if this might lead to something. For $\omega\to 0$ we have

$$
f_l(\omega) = \frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)} = 1 - \frac{1}{6}(l+1)l\omega^2 + O(\omega^2)
$$

And therefore I have

$$
\left( \frac{\sin(\omega(l+1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)} \right)^n \approx \left(1 - \frac{1}{6}(l+1)l\omega^2 \right)^n \approx e^{-\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}n(l+1)l}\omega \right)^2}
$$

And therefore the integral I want is given by

$$
I_n(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} H^n(\omega)e^{j\omega k} d\omega \approx \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}n(l+1)l}\omega \right)^2} e^{j\omega k} d\omega = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}n(l+1)l}\omega \right)^2} e^{j\omega k} d \left( \frac{\omega}{2\pi} \right)
$$

And defining $f = \frac{\omega}{2\pi}$, we end up with a known integral, such as [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html). I don't like much my argument, is really intuitive, but I believe it can be justified formally.

**Update 3**:

A last attempt and I'll give up for now.

Trying to expand

$$
g_l(\omega)^n = \left( \frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{\sin(\omega(l + 1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)} \right)^n
$$

Let me start by defining

$$
g_l(\omega) = \frac{1}{2l+1}\frac{\sin(\omega(l + 1/2))}{\sin(\omega/2)}
$$

using the equality mentioned in the update 1 I can write

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
g_l(0) = 1 \\
g^{(1)}_l(0) = 0 \\
g^{(2)}_l(0) = -\frac{(l+1)l}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right. .
$$

For $g_l(\omega)^n$ we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\left( g^n_l(\omega)^n \right)^{(1)} = n g^{n-1}_l(\omega) g^{(1)}(\omega) \\
\left( g^n_l(\omega)^n \right)^{(2)} = n g^{n-2}_l(\omega) \left( (n-1)g^{(1)}(\omega) + g^{(2)}(\omega) \right)
\end{array}
\right. \Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
g^n_l(0) = 1 \\
\left( g^n_l(0)^n \right)^{(1)} = 0 \\
\left( g^n_l(0)^n \right)^{(2)} = -\frac{n(l+1)l}{3}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

And we have

$$
g_l(\omega)^n = 1 - \frac{n(l+1)l}{6} \omega^2 + O(\omega^2)
$$

Comment: Unpacking this.. You effectively want to compute the self convolution of $h$ n times? If so, I think you're going to end up with a piecewise polynomial of some kind.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the thing is, if this were a continuous function instead of a piecewise one I would be able to compute the result. However it's a discrete function, and I'd like to end up with something similar so I can study the properties.

Comment: I might be able to transform this problem into a similar one easy to solve.

Comment: I do apologies for the updates... so many calculus mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a different way to look at the problem that involves the Fourier transform implicitly. Assuming $h(k)$ models a probability distribution, consider the sequence of $n$ random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ distributed according $h$. Easily we can find out that

$$
\overline{X_i} = 0, Var(X_i) =\frac{(l+1)l}{3}.
$$

Consider now

$$
S_n = \frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n}
$$

By the CLT we now $S_n$ will be have distribution

$$
S_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \frac{(l+1)l}{3n}}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\frac{(l+1)l}{3n}}} = \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{(l+1)l}{3n}\right)
$$

Defining $Q_n = n S_n$ by a known theorem in probability theory we can assert

$$
Q_n \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{n(l+1)l}{3}\right)
$$

Therefore my original problem translates into finding the Fourier transform of the distribution of $Q_n$, which can be easily found in this case using the link in update 1.